# not able to understand the fract function graph

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

[This graph](https://thebookofshaders.com/10/):

[image]

...is of:

```c
y = fract(sin(x)*1.0)
```

I was expecting the graph like this:

[image]

am i missing something?

I dont know how i can plot this graph in glsl so don't know how to check so i thought i can ask for help here to clear my doubt.

Comment: For me, both graphs look exactly the same, except the style of the drawing for discontinuities and that weird 0 at pi/4... Am I missing something?

Comment: yes that i meant at pi/4 first graph has value of 1 and second graph has value 0

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you expect to have `fract(sin(π/4))` return `0` but not for the same values `mod 2π`. Perhaps you misunderstood what the function does?

[As stated in the docs](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/fract.xhtml), `fract(x)` is `x - floor(x)`.

Unrolling this:

- `sin(π/4) == sqrt(2)/2`.
- `sqrt(2)/2` is approx `0.70710678118`.
- `floor(0.70710678118) == 0`.
- `0.70710678118 - 0 == 0.70710678118`

So you end up with `fract(sin(π/4)) == 0.70710678118`, which is what appears in the first graph.